Org Capture Template - Reuse the value entered
Consider the following capture template. It is asking for heading text and four properties; viz: TYPE, NAME, REFERENCE and LOCATION.
("a" "Template 1" entry 
 (file+headline 
  "~/Documents/org/org1.org" "First Heading")
 "* %^{Prompt for Heading Text} — %^{TYPE}p %^{NAME}p %^{REFERENCE}p %^{LOCATION}p %\3 ")

Suppose, %^{Prompt for Heading Text} is 'A Great Heading'. %^{NAME}p input is 'MY NAME', I expected the heading as inserted in the file to read 'A Great Heading - MY NAME' given the %\3 in the capture template. It produces the following output, instead. This is based on the documentation available here.
** A Great Heading —     % 
:PROPERTIES:
:TYPE:     Something
:NAME:    MY NAME
:REFERENCE: Something
:LOCATION: Something
:END:

How do I get the desired output?

You need to double up backslashes in strings - although I don't think that will solve your problem (I'm not sure that it can be solved: I believe that property prompts don't count for %\N or %\*N expansion - but I may be wrong.)

I was wrong: %\*N expansion works with property prompts, but only in upstream Org mode. No released version includes the capability yet. See my answer.

@NickD Thanks. But please see here. It shows use of %/N as used and refers to org mode v 9.7

Yes, I've added an edit to my answer that describes the differences between 9.7 and upstream.

Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/81310/is-it-possible-to-re-use-the-value-of-a-timestamp-prompt-within-an-org-capture.

Also see this thread on the Org mailing list.

It does work with the following template:
("a" "Template 1" entry (file+headline "~/Documents/org/org1.org" "First Heading")
           "* %^{Prompt for Heading Text} — %^{TYPE}p %^{NAME}p %^{REFERENCE}p %^{LOCATION}p %\\*3 ")


but the %\*N mechanism is not in any Org mode release yet. (N.B. Backslashes in strings act as escapes, so in order to enter a literal backslash in a string, you have to double it up.)
It was introduced through two commits on June 5, 2024 and June 11, 2024. It will be generally available with Org mode 9.8. The two commits are:

org-capture-templates: New placeholder to refer to %^{prompt}X answers
org-capture-fill-template: Allow recursive capture while expanding template


EDIT: In 9.7, undecorated %^{prompt} entries can be reused with %\N, but decorated %^{prompt}X entries (with X one of g,G,t,T,u,U,C,L) or %^{prop}p property entries cannot be so reused: the 9.7 code stores the former entries in a list as they are entered, but does not do so for the latter entries. The commits above (among other things) add a second variable and ensure that the decorated all the entries are stored on this second list as they are entered, so they too can be reused later. The old variable still stores all the undecorated entries for backward compatibility, but there will be no need for that in new templates.
The doc string of org-capture-templates after these commits now reads as follows:

%\1 ... %\N Insert the text entered at the nth %^{prompt (but not %^{prompt}X), where N is a number, starting from 1.
%\*1...%\*N Same as \N, but for all the prompts, including %^{prompt} and %^{prompt}X.

(emphasis added) which clarifies the situation a bit, although the description of %\*N contains a typo, and it still does not mention %^{prop}p. [Previously, I thought the description was inaccurate but I was wrong.]

@NicD Thanks. This clarifies things. And I am able to get the output when I use %\1 (there is one undecorated prompt) instead of %\3.

So what else is needed in order for you to accept the answer?

Oops. Sorry. Missed it earlier. Have done it.
